# In Pyspark, how do I populate a new column in one dataframe using calculations from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In df1 I have

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|     ID1|start_date| stop_date|
+--------+----------+----------+
|50194077|2012-05-22|2012-05-25|
|50194077|2012-05-19|2012-05-22|
|50194077|2012-06-15|2012-06-18|
|50127135|2016-05-12|2016-05-15|
             ...
+--------+----------+----------+
```

In df2 I have

```
+----------+-------------------+------------------+
|       ID2|               date|                 X|
+----------+-------------------+------------------+
|  50127135|2016-06-10 00:00:00| 24.14699999999999|
|  50127135|2015-08-01 00:00:00|17.864999999999995|
|  50127135|2015-05-10 00:00:00|1.6829999999999998|
|  50127135|2014-07-02 00:00:00| 5.301000000000002|
                    ...
+----------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I would like to add a column to df1 called X_sum which contains the sum of the X values that meet the conditions ID2 == ID1 and date is between start_date and stop_date.

I tried

```
def f(start_date, stop_date, ID, df2):
    sub_df2 = df2[df2['date'].between(start_date, stop_date) & df2.ID2 == ID]

    return sub_df2.select(F.sum(sub_df2['X'])).collect()[0][0]

udf_f = udf(cumulative_func, DoubleType())

df1 = df1.withColumn('X_sum', 
        udf_f(df1.start_date, df1.stop_date, df1.ID1, F.lit('X'), df2))
```

(and a few other variants), but I don't think pyspark likes how I'm trying to include df2.

I'm using python 2.7 and Spark 1.6.

Comment: You need to join both DFs on your key, you can't just take a column from one DF and stick it on the other

Comment: @eliasah Thank you for the comment. I spent some time searching for things like "spark dataframe join with calculation' before posting, suspecting a join would help, but it never became clear to me how/when to calculate the sum of X. Is it during the join or after the join? Either way how is it done? Thanks again.